# Auto advance to next question in a questionnaire on user response

Tags: forms, user-behavior, user-expectation

We am creating a survey (9 questions), each of which has four options (more like user preference with no *one correct* answer). We intend to show him one question at a time and let him move to the next one once he has selected an option. Most users would see this page 1-2 times overall but we want a majority of them to finish the questionnaire.

One choice is that we put a radio button next to the options, and the user clicks next to advance. So, the user will need to click 18 times.

Other choice is that we design the options as buttons (2x2), with the click taking him to the next question automatically, with a previous button to let him go back if he wants to change the option. The last question would have an explicit submit button. So total 10 clicks for 9 questions in most cases.

I have gone though the following similar question, and am wondering if the second option would be unnerving for users (even with the previous and final submit button).

[Auto Advance to Next Field](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22508/auto-advance-to-next-field/22515#22515)

[Should Forms Auto Submit (Auto Advance) When Questions Are Correctly Filled In?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52695/should-forms-auto-submit-auto-advance-when-questions-are-correctly-filled-in/52729#52729)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been there, done that. Here's what my thought process is. Users have a tendency to learn, so as soon as they select an option against the first question, they'll know that they're advanced to the next question automatically. But you need to have a transition between questions that shows how the question has changed. UI would play a special role in this experience (it always does). It also depends how easy it is to go back to a certain question in the form/questionnaire. Also, let the user save manually, don't save after the final answer's selection, use a special "save" button.
Reminds me of https://www.typeform.com/examples/#Insight

Would all of the options against questions be the same, or could they be different?

Comment: We went ahead with the auto-advance with an explicit submit and an optional previous (to change previous selections). The options are different for various questions. Thanks for the example link.

Comment: Here is the final outcome https://www.taurowealth.com/Account/InvestingTraits, put anything you want in the first form and don't click register on the last page, unless you are interested in investing in Indian stock market. I could not post the link earlier because the form required a registration to view; now registration is at the end. Feedback welcome.